# How to process two RDDs serially in Spark?

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

As I was hitting the resource limit in my Spark program, I want to divide the processing into iterations, and upload results from each iteration to the HDFS, as shown below.

```
do something using first rdd
upload the output to hdfs

do something using second rdd
upload the output to hdfs
```

But as far as I know, Spark will try to run those two in parallel. Is there a way to wait for the processing of the first rdd, before processing the second rdd?

Comment: Who told you that spark will try to process both RDDs in parallel ? That's incorrect !

Comment: So this will be processed serially?

Comment: Yes ! If you'd have tested it, you would have known.

Comment: Awesome. I will test it in a moment.

Comment: Would be great to have more information about how you are thinking to process the data. Does the second RDD depends on the first RDD? Does the second RDD is the result of the first process or is a completely different RDD? What do you mean with upload the data to the HDFS, it was not in the HDFS already?

Comment: @dbustosp those are two totally different RDDs, and no the data was not in the HDFS already.

Comment: @pythonic remember that RDD is a distributed dataset.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand where you're confused.  Within a single RDD, the partitions will run in parallel to each other.  However, two RDDs will run sequentially to each other (unless you code otherwise).

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to wait for the processing of the first rdd, before processing the second rdd

You have the RDD, so why do you need to wait and read from disk again?

Do some transformations on the RDD, write to disk in the first action, and continue with that same RDD to perform a second action.

Comment: Possible to do but then I would need to make more changes in my program.

Comment: You could show some code, but by "second rdd", I assume you meant it came from the first one originally